# Interactive Bar Chart Using Shiny - Graph changes based on selected columns

Tags: r, shiny

I am teaching myself r and shiny and trying to make an interactive bar chart where the user can change the chart based on columns. I keep getting errors with this code. Any help would be appreciated! My data has four columns: v, one, two, three. The first column is characters and the last three are numbers. I want to change the bar chart based on the y axis (columns: one, two and three). Right now, the error I   am getting is: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv('scoring.csv')

data$v <- as.character(data$v)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Scoring"),
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "scoring", label = "Select a score:", c("Scoring Method 1", "Scoring Method 2", "Scoring Method 3"))),

    mainPanel(
       plotOutput(outputId = "bar")
    )
)


#browser()
server <- function(input, output) {

    new_data <- reactive({
        selected_score = as.numeric(input$"scoring")
        if (selected_score == "Scoring Method 1"){(data[data$one])}
        if (selected_score == "Scoring Method 2"){(data[data$two])}
        if (selected_score == "Scoring Method 3"){(data[data$three])}
    }) 
    #browser()
    output$bar <- renderPlot({
        newdata <- new_data()
        p <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x=reorder(v, -selected_score), selected_score, y = selected_score, fill=v)) +
         geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill="darkblue") + 
         theme_minimal() +
         ggtitle("Sports")
    barplot(p, height = 400, width = 200)
})
```

}

## Run the application

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: At what point in the code is the error appearing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code.  In the server part, please use `input$scoring`, instead of `input$"scoring"`.
First, in ui `selectInput` could be defined as

```
selectInput(inputId = "scoring", label = "Select a score:", c("Scoring Method 1"="one", 
                                                                  "Scoring Method 2"="two", 
                                                                  "Scoring Method 3"="three")))
```

Second, your reactive dataframe `new_data()` could be defined as shown below:

```
new_data <- reactive({
    d <- data %>% mutate(selected_score = input$scoring)
    d
  })
```

Third, `ggplot` could be defined as

```
output$bar <- renderPlot({
     newdata <- new_data()
p <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x=v, y = newdata[[as.name(selected_score)]], fill=v)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge", fill="blue") +
      theme_bw() +
      #scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "green", "red")) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
      ggtitle("Sports")
      p
        })
```

Please note that you had an extra `selected_score` variable within `aes`.  My suggestion would be to play with it to reorder x, and review some online or youtube videos on R Shiny.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am still getting an error: non-numeric argument to binary operator. Just to note, I could successfully make each bar chart in rstudio I just can't make it interactive using shiny.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting error, as I do not have access to your data.  Perhaps you can post it as a dataframe.  For example, when I use the sample dataframe below I do not get any errors.  `data <- data.frame(
  one = c(1, 2, 3 ),
  two = c(2, 4, 6),
  three = c(3, 6, 9),
  v = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
  Cost = c( 4, 2, 3)
)'

Comment: To get interactive plot, you need call `ggplotly(p)`.  Then use `renderPlotly` and `plotlyOutput`, instead of `renderPlot` and `plotOutput`, respectively..

Comment: After adding the above suggestion, I  now get this error: Warning: Error in .subset2: invalid subscript type 'symbol'. Confused about what this means and even where this error is occurring because it shows no line number.

Comment: Please edit your query to show the new program that is giving error.  I do not get any errors.  Perhaps you have a different version of RStudio or R.  Also, may be your data is different.  Please include a small amount of data (similar to what I included in the comment above) than I can replicate your error.